# SNMP read only risk of enabling

Tags: networking

We are currently thinking of enabling SNMP read on our routers  and switches. What are the risk of doing so. If the read mode is compromised how much damge could we be expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that unauthenticated reads could leak information about your network infrastructure, subnet definitions or metrics. Sure a potential bug in the SNMP agent could lead to even more problems. However, this is the same for all services you run on a host.

I would configure your firewalls in a way that only a certain machine or a set of machines which you own will be allowed to access the SNMP service on those machines. Further I would secure the access using authentication.